# Xamarin Android VS 2019: Can't deploy on Chromebook, get error "The 'run-as' tool has been disabled on this device."

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an Android app with Xamarin on Visual Studio 2019, on Windows. I could successfully deploy the app to an old Android phone, but when I tried to deploy to a relatively new Acer Chromebook, I hit a snag. The connection from Windows to Chromebook was established, the command

adb devices

lists the Chromebook, and Visual Studio also shows it on the Run toolbar. But when I click the Run button, I get the message "There were deployment errors" and the following error appears in the error list window:

**The 'run-as' tool has been disabled on this device. Either enable it by activating the developer options on the device or by setting `ro.boot.disable_runas` to `false`.**

On my Chromebook, Linux was installed, Developer Options are On and ADB Debugging is also On.

Curiously, after this failed deployment, the app appears on the Chromebook's Apps list as "AndroidApp1". But it won't run, I just see a blank screen.

So how do I set this mysterious ro.boot.disable_runas property to false on my Chromebook? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "Fast deployment" under Android Options fixes this error and the app deploys. I'd still like to know how to set the ro.boot.disable_runas property to false.

Comment: Could you mark it as answer ? It's helpful to others who's facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a device property which is visible in adb, but devices can disable it from being changed. My Lenovo refuses to set it.

Try opening a "Linux terminal" in the developer mode apps, then...

```
$ adb shell
$ getprop ro.boot.disable_runas
1
$ setprop ro.boot.disable_runas 0
setprop: failed to set property 'ro.boot.disable_runas' to '0'
$
```

Perhaps it will work on yours. I just unchecked the Fast Deploy option in the Xamarin Android project debug properties.